# Why can't I check for updates in Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

I get the following error message when I try to check for updates:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/dists/https/ppa/ubuntu/natty/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/dists/https/ppa/ubuntu/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/dists/https/ppa/ubuntu/natty/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/dists/https/ppa/ubuntu/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What can I do to correct this? This is a new installation of Natty. I installed updates only once, and subsequently I have only received this error message when trying to check for more updates.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: It is a new installation but you had the time to broke your sources list with a wrong ppa. Anyway this should not prevent the upgrade, unless you completely compromised your sources list.

Answer (score 4):

Your have an invalid entry in your sources. It can't imagina how can this happen in a new installation. Anyway:

1. Open the Software Centre
2. Click on the *Edit* menu, select Software Sources.
3. A new window will open, select the "Other Software" tab
4. Uncheck everything but "Canonical Partners" and "Independent"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it may happened because of some reasons:

1. your internet connection.
2. your apt source.list file corrupted.